# ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias- PIG SCRIPT

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, tweets, elephantbird

I have been facing this issue from long time. I tried to solve this but i couldn't. I need some experts advice to solve this.

I am trying to load a sample tweets json file.

**sample.json;-**

```
{"filter_level":"low","retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":"FilmFan","truncated":false,"lang":"en","in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":689085590822891521,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"6048122","timestamp_ms":"1453125782100","in_reply_to_status_id":null,"created_at":"Mon Jan 18 14:03:02 +0000 2016","favorite_count":0,"place":null,"coordinates":null,"text":"@filmfan hey its time for you guys follow @acadgild To #AchieveMore and participate in contest Win Rs.500 worth vouchers","contributors":null,"geo":null,"entities":{"symbols":[],"urls":[],"hashtags":[{"text":"AchieveMore","indices":[56,68]}],"user_mentions":[{"id":6048122,"name":"Tanya","indices":[0,8],"screen_name":"FilmFan","id_str":"6048122"},{"id":2649945906,"name":"ACADGILD","indices":[42,51],"screen_name":"acadgild","id_str":"2649945906"}]},"is_quote_status":false,"source":"<a href=\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck<\/a>","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_user_id":6048122,"retweet_count":0,"id_str":"689085590822891521","user":{"location":"India ","default_profile":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"statuses_count":86548,"lang":"en","profile_link_color":"94D487","profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/197865769/1436198000","id":197865769,"following":null,"protected":false,"favourites_count":1002,"profile_text_color":"000000","verified":false,"description":"Proud Indian, Digital Marketing Consultant,Traveler, Foodie, Adventurer, Data Architect, Movie Lover, Namo Fan","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","name":"Bahubali","profile_background_color":"000000","created_at":"Sat Oct 02 17:41:02 +0000 2010","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":4467,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/664486535040000000/GOjDUiuK_normal.jpg","geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","follow_request_sent":null,"url":null,"utc_offset":19800,"time_zone":"Chennai","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":false,"friends_count":810,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","screen_name":"Ashok_Uppuluri","id_str":"197865769","profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/664486535040000000/GOjDUiuK_normal.jpg","listed_count":50,"is_translator":false}}
```

I have tried to load this json file using **ELEPHANT BIRD**

**script:-**

```
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar 
REGISTER elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar 
REGISTER guava-11.0.2.jar 
REGISTER avro-1.7.7.jar
REGISTER piggybank-0.12.0.jar


twitter = LOAD 'sample.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader();

B = foreach twitter generate (chararray)$0#'created_at' as created_at,(chararray)$0#'id' as id,(chararray)$0#'id_str' as id_str,(chararray)$0#'text' as text,(chararray)$0#'source' as source,com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.piggybank.JsonStringToMap($0#'entities') as entities,(boolean)$0#'favorited' as favorited;

describe B;
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
B: {created_at: chararray,id: chararray,id_str: chararray,text: chararray,source: chararray,entitis: map[chararray],favorited: boolean}
```

But when I tried to **DUMP B** the follwoing **error** has occured

**ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B**

I am providing the complete logs here.

> 2016-09-11 14:07:57,184 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size before optimization: 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,184 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MultiQueryOptimizer
>   - MR plan size after optimization: 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,194 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM
>   Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,194 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRScriptState - Pig script
>   settings are added to the job 2016-09-11 14:07:57,194 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is not set, set to default 0.3 2016-09-11 14:07:57,199 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler
>   - Setting up single store job 2016-09-11 14:07:57,199 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Key [pig.schematuple] is
>   false, will not generate code. 2016-09-11 14:07:57,199 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Starting process to move
>   generated code to distributed cacche 2016-09-11 14:07:57,199 [main]
>   INFO org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleFrontend - Distributed cache not
>   supported or needed in local mode. Setting key
>   [pig.schematuple.local.dir] with code temp directory:
>   /tmp/1473583077199-0 2016-09-11 14:07:57,206 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 1 map-reduce job(s) waiting for submission. 2016-09-11 14:07:57,207 [JobControl] INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot
>   initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= -
>   already initialized 2016-09-11 14:07:57,208 [JobControl] **WARN
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader - No job jar file set.
>   User classes may not be found.** See Job or Job#setJar(String).
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,211 [JobControl] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input
>   paths to process : 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,211 [JobControl] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total
>   input paths (combined) to process : 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,212
>   [JobControl] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - number of
>   splits:1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,216 [JobControl] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter - Submitting tokens for job:
>   job_local360376249_0009 2016-09-11 14:07:57,267 [JobControl] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job - The url to track the job:
>   http://localhost:8080/ 2016-09-11 14:07:57,267 [Thread-214] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - OutputCommitter set in
>   config null 2016-09-11 14:07:57,270 [Thread-214] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - File
>   Output Committer Algorithm version is 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,270
>   [Thread-214] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter -
>   FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output
>   directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false 2016-09-11
>   14:07:57,270 [Thread-214] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner
>   - OutputCommitter is org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,271 [Thread-214] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Waiting for map tasks
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,272 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - Starting task:
>   attempt_local360376249_0009_m_000000_0 2016-09-11 14:07:57,277
>   [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - File
>   Output Committer Algorithm version is 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,277
>   [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter -
>   FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output
>   directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false 2016-09-11
>   14:07:57,277 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task - Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree :
>   [ ] 2016-09-11 14:07:57,278 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask - Processing split: Number of splits
>   :1 Total Length = 2416 Input split[0]: Length = 2416 ClassName:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit Locations:
>   ----------------------- 2016-09-11 14:07:57,282 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader
>   - Current split being processed file:/root/PIG/PIG/sample.json:0+2416 2016-09-11 14:07:57,282 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter - File
>   Output Committer Algorithm version is 1 2016-09-11 14:07:57,282
>   [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter -
>   FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output
>   directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false 2016-09-11
>   14:07:57,288 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not
>   set... will not generate code. 2016-09-11 14:07:57,290 [LocalJobRunner
>   Map Task Executor #0] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigMapOnly$Map
>   - Aliases being processed per job phase (AliasName[line,offset]): M: twitter[20,10],B[21,4] C: R: 2016-09-11 14:07:57,291 [Thread-214] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - map task executor complete.
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,296 [Thread-214] **WARN
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local360376249_0009
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found
>   interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)**
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter, but class was expected at
>   com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.PigCounterHelper.incrCounter(PigCounterHelper.java:55)
>   at
>   com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.LzoBaseLoadFunc.incrCounter(LzoBaseLoadFunc.java:70)
>   at
>   com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader.getNext(JsonLoader.java:130)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:204)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:556)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-09-11 14:07:57,467
>   [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - HadoopJobId: job_local360376249_0009 2016-09-11 14:07:57,467 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Processing aliases B,twitter 2016-09-11 14:07:57,467 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - detailed locations: M: twitter[20,10],B[21,4] C: R: 2016-09-11 14:07:57,468 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 0% complete 2016-09-11 14:07:57,468 [main] **WARN org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want Pig to stop immediately on failure.** 2016-09-11 14:07:57,468 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - job job_local360376249_0009 has failed! Stop running all dependent jobs 2016-09-11 14:07:57,468 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   - 100% complete 2016-09-11 14:07:57,469 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM
>   Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,469 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics - Cannot initialize JVM
>   Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
>   2016-09-11 14:07:57,469 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce
>   job(s) failed! 2016-09-11 14:07:57,470 [main] INFO
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.SimplePigStats - Script
>   Statistics: HadoopVersionPigVersionUserIdStartedAtFinishedAtFeatures
>   2.7.1.2.3.4.7-40.15.0.2.3.4.7-4root2016-09-11 14:07:572016-09-11 14:07:57UNKNOWN Failed! Failed Jobs: JobIdAliasFeatureMessageOutputs
>   job_local360376249_0009B,twitterMAP_ONLYMessage: Job
>   failed!file:/tmp/temp252944192/tmp-470484503, Input(s): Failed to read
>   data from "file:///root/PIG/PIG/sample.json" Output(s): Failed to
>   produce result in "file:/tmp/temp252944192/tmp-470484503" Counters:
>   Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable Memory
>   Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total
>   records proactively spilled: 0 Job DAG: job_local360376249_0009

And please give a clarification on how to use jar files,

And what are the versions to use.I am so confused which version to use.

Someone says use Elephant Bird, and Someone says use AVRO. But I have with both non of them are working.

Please help.

Mohan.V

Answer (score 0):

I got it on my own.
It is of jar versions issue.
**script:-**

```
REGISTER elephant-bird-core-4.1.jar 
REGISTER elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar 
REGISTER elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar
```

And it worked fine.